# Can I execute a plain SQL statement with the Spring JDBC template?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about the use of **JdbcTemplate**. On the study material I found this question:

> Can I execute a plain SQL statement with the JDBC template?

What exactly is a **plain SQL statement**? Is it a standard SQL query? or what?

If it is a standard SQL query (not something like JPQL) I think that the answer is yes because I can do something like it:

```
public Date getOldest() {
    String sql = “select max(dob) from PERSON”;
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Date.class);
}

public long getPersonCount() {
    String sql = “select count(*) from PERSON”;
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class);
}
```

But I am absolutly not sure to have understand the sense of the question and what exactly represent a **plain SQL statement**.

What do you think about?

Comment: I think you are correct. Unlike JPA which is implemented in Spring Data JPA which is working with JPQL, JdbcTemplate is made to execute standard SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view:

- a non-plain sql is a query in jql.
- Some stuff is quite complicate to achive with jql (ie. joins over a few tables) in an already existent data scheme.
- jpa requests primary keys in tables - which is not always the case in existent databases
- the question aims on 'i wanna have a fallback to traditional queries to do my everyday's life'